# Java Netbeans Derby embedded database not running on standalone mode (without Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans, derby

Hello I'm working with:

Windows 7 (64 bits) + Java 8 + NetBeans 8.0 and learning embedded databases with Derby.

I follow a simple sample "Using The Built-In Derby Database In NetBeans Starting A Java DB Application In NetBeans 6.1"

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCY4mcKa8-E

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwCe0-uYYiE

The sample is fine, and the program run OK on Netbeans.

Then I Create and Build so I can learn to pack and deploy the program on anothers computers.

If I open the /dist folder and run the JAR file nothing happens.. The only way to run the program is if I open Netbeans and start the JB server.

But I cant run the program without Netbeans support.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a path issue (java not on the path).

Open a command prompt and type "java -version".  If you get "java is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file" you need to add java to path env variables.

Comment: Hello whatever5599451. If I type "java -version" on the starup menu a Window with my version of Java Standard Edition 7 .... showup, and if I type the same on the CMD black windows I have "Java version "1.8.0_11"... I dont know what is wrong and I searched on the web and nothing...

Comment: I solved the trouble. All I need to do was to use relative path to the database !